# Node.js req.body undefined in form-data content-type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-data

Here I have created the small demo for this form-data passing API. Now I'm checking this API using postman but I'm not getting any data.

**Code**

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: "50mb"
  })
);

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: "50mb",
    extended: true
  })
);

app.post('/form-data', (req, res) => {
  console.log("form-data ->> ", req.body) 
});

server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(4000[![enter image description here][1]][1], () => {
  console.log(`Server started`);
});
```

**Server log**

```
Server started
form-data ->> {}
```

[image]

**Header**
[image]

[image]

Comment: What headers did you include in your `POST`?

Comment: If the content-type is indeed `form-data` or `multipart/form-data`, then you don't show any Express middleware that knows how to parse that, so naturally `req.body` will be empty because nothing read or parsed the body.  If you have to use this content-type, then you will want to get some middleware such as multer that can read and parse that content-type.  Right now, your server  code only handles `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-types and your post has neither of those.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have set `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in request header.

Comment: Your screenshot from Postman shows `multipart/form-data`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @JayBhajiyawala - You'll need to [add middleware that supports `multipart/form-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=express%20multipart). From [`npm body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser): *"**This does not handle multipart bodies,** due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules: `busboy` and `connect-busboy`, `multiparty` and `connect-multiparty`, `formidable`, `multer`."* *(their emphasis)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code with small changes.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer();

const app = express();

// for parsing application/json
app.use(
    bodyParser.json({
        limit: "50mb",
    })
);
// for parsing application/xwww-form-urlencoded
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        limit: "50mb",
        extended: true,
    })
);

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array());

app.post("/form-data", (req, res) => {
    console.log(`\nform-data ->> ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
    res.send(req.body);
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I removed your server initialization since we can use app listen directly from the expressjs.

And I can send post with "form-data", "x-www-form-urlencoded", or "raw" successfully.

You might double-check on which tutorial you following. Since express documentation is clear enough.

*Edited
I added multer to parsing the form-data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have copied your entire code and try to check it but in form-data, I'm getting null object.

Comment: @JayBhajiyawala Could you check my updated code, I add multer to parsing the form-data.

Comment: I have checked your new multer code change @taipei, and it's damn working. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JayBhajiyawala, This is awesome answer that I am looking for. Btw when I used `app.use(upload.array())`, I am getting this error: **array(fieldName: string, maxCount?: number): RequestHandler;**, **An argument for 'fieldName' was not provided.**. I wanted to use `form-data` method, so I installed `multer` as you wrote in the answer, (Since this is typescript, I also installed `@types/multer`.)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using multer as middleware on the post route with other middle middlewares put the multer middleware first.

```
app.post(
    "/api/private/buyer/add-buyer",
    [
        upload, verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
    ],
    controller.createBuyer
);
```

here upload is multer middleware I put it first it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, I had moved the multer middleware into the request handler itself. Now i moved it back and it worked